# Ionic 1 vs Ionic 2 app load times

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

The bare minimum app created with Ionic 1 ("ionic start blank") takes less than ONE second to load on my android device (HTC 816) while a minimal Ionic 2 app ("ionic start blank --v2") takes more than 10 seconds! On the SAME device! Why is that?

I tried everything I could think of, like release build instead on debug, Crosswalk, removing ALL plugins and I even removed ALL html and unnecessary code from the app! But still, the ionic 2 app takes more than 10 seconds to load.
shouldn't angular2/ionic2 have better performance!

Ionic 1 app takes 2.5megs on the device while 4.5megs for ionic 2

Am I missing anything here? I mean 10 seconds! vs less than a second! come on!

Any reply is very appreciated :)

Comment: I started working with ionic 2 yesterday and faced the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the load time of v2 compared to v1 is more, but using `--prod` flag reduces it significantly `ionic build android --prod` currently i have 13 components , 10 plugins , 2 directives , and 3 service.... the app takes more than 6 seconds after the splashscreen to load.

I have done quite some research on this issue.. the loading has improved since RC.5 and Im hoping it continues improving down the road... if they only do something about `NavController` where lazy loading is possible and not load all the modules at once , it would drastically improve loading time.... for now make sure you have everything up to latest version (e.g. ionic-native , adding plugins with `ionic add` , and try using life cycle event like `ngOnInit` `ionViewDidLoad` rather than `constructor` on most pages(its depends)) and use `--prod`flag when running/building.